# Why aspnet_compiler requires virtual path (-v) parameter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, precompile

I want to prepare a pre-compiled package of ASP.NET MVC 4 site.

I can precompile it using commandline as follows:

```
aspnet_compiler -nologo -v / -p "C:\WebSite1" -u "C:\TargetPath"
```

However it baffles me, why `aspnet_compiler` requires virtual path. What if I decide later on to deploy this package to an IIS server under different path? Could it cause some run-time problems?

By deployment I mean here simple xcopy deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifiy the physical path of the source with the -p switch, then the virtual path is required.  I reluctantly submit this page http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/precompiling-your-website-cs for some info on how the -v can play in with app relative references ie ~/path/file.  What he says needs more qualification and does not appear to apply to apps under the default IIS site.

His explanation is that using -v /MySite will change references from ~/path/file to ~/MySite/path/file.  However I have not experienced this behaviour.  Atleast as far as compiling apps that are under the default IIS website (regardless of being on the root of the site or nested).  If I compile with for instance /v kart, inline references and codebehind references to "~/path/file" arrive in the dll as "~/path/file", not "~/kart/path/file".  I have had no runtime problems deploying my WebForm apps elsewhere where the app root is now at a different path.

If you are compiling apps that are under the default IIS website, it is redundant to use -p with the physical path to the source and -v with the virtual path.  If you omit the -p switch it will compile the same as only using the -v.  Being redundant with the -p and physical source path may be nice when reviewing a batch file to have the source location documented.

Comment: To satisy my curiosty I created a new IIS site and added a new app to it. Compiling with the -v and a virtual path did not modify app root relative references as the linked article suggests.  I don't see any concern for deployment path issues using -v.